# Select random non-repeating rows per user

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, math, random

The use case is, that I have a table *products* and *user_match_product*. For a specific user, I want to select X random products, for which that user has no match.

The naive way to do that, would be to make something like

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT p_id FROM user_match_product WHERE u_id = 123) ORDER BY random() LIMIT X`

but that will become a performance bottleneck when having millions of rows.

I thought of some possible solutions which I will present here now. I would love to hear about your solutions for that problem or suggestions regarding my solutions.

**Solution 1: Trust the randomness**

Based on the fact that the product ids are monotonically increasing, one could optimistically generate `X*C` random numbers `R_i` where `i` between `1` and `X*C`, which are in the range `[min_id, max_id]`, and hope that a select like the following will return X elements.

`SELECT * FROM products p1 WHERE p1.id IN (R_1, R_2, ..., R_XC) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_match_product WHERE u_id = 123 AND p_id = p1.id) LIMIT X`

Advantages

- If the random number generator is good, this will probably work very well within *O(1)*
- Old and newly added products have the same probability of being choosen

Disadvantages

- If the number of matches is near to the number of products, the collision probability might be very high.

**Solution 2: Block-wise PRNG**

One could create a permutation function `permutate(seed, start, end, value)` for the domain `[START, END]` that uses a `seed` for randomness. At time `t0` a user `A` has `0` matched products and observes that `E0` products exist. The first block for the user `A` at `t0` is for the domain `[1, E0]`. The user remembers a counter `C` which initially is `0`.

To select X products the user `A` first has to create the permutations `P_i` like

`P_i = permutate(seed, START, END, C + i)`

The following has to hold for the function.

- `permutate(seed, start, end, value)` is element of `[start, end]`
- `value` is element of `[start, end]`

The following query will return X non-repeating elements.

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (P_1, ..., P_X)`

When `C` reaches END, the next block is allocated by using `END + 1` as the new `START`, the current count of products `E1` as new `END`. The `seed` and `C` stay the same.

Advantages

- No collisions possible
- Guaranteed *O(1)*

Disadvantages

- The current block has to be finished before new products can be selected

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Postgres but that shouldn't matter I guess? Does Oracle offer any special feature that assist me in that matter?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with approach #1.

You can get a first estimate of `C` by counting the user's rows in `user_match_product` (supposed unique). If he already possesses half the possible products, selecting twice the number of random products seems a good heuristic.

You can also have a last-ditch correction that verifies that the number of extracted products is actually X. If it was, say, X/3, you'd need to run the same extraction two more times (avoiding already-generated random product IDs), and increase that user's `C` constant by a factor of three.

Also, knowing what the range of product IDs is, you could select random numbers in that range that do not appear in `user_match_product` (i.e. your first stage query is only against `user_match_product`) which is bound to have a (much?) lower cardinality than `products`. Then, those IDs that pass the test can be safely selected from `products`.

Comment: Although I could switch at any time from #2 to #1, but not from #1 to #2, you would recommend this? Most of the time the retrieval will be done in *O(1)* but sometimes it might take longer. This is what concerns me with approach #1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose X products that the user doesn't have, the first thing that comes to mind is to enumerate the products and use `order by rand()` (or the equivalent, depending on the database).  This is your first solution:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_match_product WHERE ump.p_id = p.id and u_id = 123)
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT X;
```

A simple way to make this more efficient is to choose an arbitrary subset.  You can actually do this using `random()` as well, but in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
WHERE random() < Y AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_match_product WHERE ump.p_id = p.id and u_id = 123)
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT X;
```

The question is:  what is "Y"?  Well, let's say the number of products is P and the user has U.  Then, if we choose a random set of (X + U) products, we can definitely get X products the user does not have.  This suggests that the expression `random() < (X + U) / P` would be sufficient.  Alas, the vagaries of random numbers say that sometimes we would get enough and sometimes not enough.  Let's add a factor such as 3 to be safe.  This is actually really, really, really, really safe for most values of X, U, and P.

The idea is a query such as this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as p FROM Products) v1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as u FROM User_Match_Product WHERE u_id = 123) v2
WHERE random() < 3 * (u + x) / p AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM User_Match_Product WHERE ump.p_id = p.id and ump.u_id = 123)
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT X;
```

Note that these calculations require a small amount of time with appropriate indexes on `Products` and `User_Match_Product`.

So, if you have 1,000,000 products and a typical user has 20.  You want to recommend 10 more.  Then the expression (20 + 10)*3/1000000 --> 90/1000000.  This query will scan the products table, pull out 90 rows *randomly* and then sort them and choose an appropriate 10 rows.  Sorting 90 rows is, essentially, constant time relative to the original operation.

For many purposes, the cost of the table scan is acceptable.  It sure beats the cost of sorting all the data, for instance.

The alternative approach is to load all products for a user into the application.  Then pull a random product out and compare to the list:

```
select p.id
from Products p cross join
     (select min(id) as minid, max(id) as maxid as p from Products) v1
where p.id >= minid + random() * (maxid - minid)
order by p.id
limit 1;
```

(Note the calculation can be done outside the query so you can just plug in a constant.)

Many query optimizers will resolve this query constant time by doing an index scan.  You can then check in the application whether the user has the product already.  This would then run about X times for the user, providing O(1) performance.  However, this has rather bad worst case performance:  if there are not X available products, it will run indefinitely.  Of course, additional logic can fix this problem.

Comment: I have to think more about what you wrote, but this operation will be invoked very often, so putting it into memory is not an option. Therefore a table scan also is not an option.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov . . . There is nothing in my solution about putting "it" into memory, except for the list of products that a given user already has.